# needed to remove image extension using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to change or redirect the "**example.com/photos/logo.jpg**" to "**example.com/photos/logo**" when user comes from google image search.

Therefore I've used:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} photos/.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.google.[a-z]{2,4}(.[a-z]{2,4})?/url\?.*$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=\?.*$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(.*bot.*|slurp) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.google.[a-z]{2,4}(.[a-z]{2,4})?/url\?.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=\?.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(.*bot.*|slurp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^photos/(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /photos/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```